# La virgule entre sujet et verbe est-elle vraiment incorrecte ?

Tags: verbes, ponctuation, sujet

Il m'arrive souvent de lire des textes dans lesquels l'usage de la virgule ne correspond pas à la vision que je m'en fais : virgules entre sujet et verbe, mais également entre verbe et objet, au début ou à la fin d'une énumération... Il s'agit d'usages que j'ai toujours considérés comme fautifs, et pourtant je les vois dans des textes très officiels, souvent de nature juridique, ainsi que dans les œuvres d'auteurs tout-à-fait reconnus.

Du coup je me pose la question : **l'insertion d'une virgule entre sujet et verbe** (par exemple) **est-elle forcément fautive ?** Y a-t-il même une règle incontestable à ce sujet ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En cherchant à répondre à cette question, je suis tombé sur un article très intéressant : *[La virgule entre sujet et verbe : petite histoire d'un emploi oublié](http://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_2004_num_102_1_2561)*, par Jacques Dürrenmatt (in *l'Information Grammaticale*, vol. 102 n° 1, pp. 31-34, 2004).

**Version courte :** il ne semble pas y avoir de règle définitive sur la question, mais des justifications possibles pour l'un et l'autre choix, suivant les cas.

L'auteur fait la distinction entre deux systèmes de ponctuation, un système **pneumatique** (ou respiratoire) et un système **logique**. Le système pneumatique est apparemment celui qui correspond au premier usage de la ponctuation, celui de scander la phrase déclamée et de rythmer le souffle (d'où son nom). Dans ce système, la virgule est justifiée à partir du moment où elle correspond à une pause dans la déclamation, même si cette pause ne correspond pas forcément à une séparation syntaxique réelle. C'est ainsi qu'on peut voir des virgules entre sujet et verbe, notamment, et en particulier lorsque le sujet est suffisamment long pour occuper une respiration (ou lorsque l'auteur tient à une emphase particulière). L'article donne quelques exemples intéressants :

> Et d'abord Georges Limbour, ne vit pas comme tout le monde. (Aragon, *Soleils bas*, 1925)
>
> La venue des faux christs et des faux prophètes, sembloit être un plus prochain acheminement à la dernière ruine. (Bauzée, *Grammaire générale*, Barbou, 1767)
>
> Le plaisir de soulager un infortuné, est un remède sûr contre la
>   peine que nous fait sa présence. (id.)
>
> L'homme qui est insensible aux malheurs de ses semblables, est
>   un égoïste. (F. Noël et C. Chapsal, *Grammaire française sur un plan très méthodique*, Maire-Nyon, 38e édition, 1845)

L'article mentionne la coexistence, aux mêmes périodes, de ce système avec un système logique, dans lequel la ponctuation doit servir la clarté structurelle et grammaticale d'un texte aussi bien que son intelligibilité orale. Apparemment, suivant les auteurs et les théoriciens, l'un ou l'autre aspect peut être considéré comme prédominant. Il est notamment donné un exemple de Racine, sans une virgule que certains grammairiens auraient pourtant acceptée :

> Celui qui met un frein à la fureur des flots
>   Sait aussi des méchants arrêter les complots.

L'auteur de l'article explique que dans le courant du XIXe siècle, le système logique a pris le dessus sur le système pneumatique, en partie sous l'influence des typographes et des compositeurs. Est donné en exemple l'évolution de la ponctuation entre deux éditions d'un texte de Chateaubriand, dans lequel les choix des éditeurs entre 1803 et 1861 montrent une évolution en faveur du système logique.

À l'époque contemporaine, l'auteur semble admettre que suivant les auteurs et les *ponctueurs* (sic), l'usage montre une nette prédominance du système logique, et donc un certain abandon de la virgule entre sujet et verbe, sans toutefois que la pratique ait complètement disparu, ni qu'elle soit injustifiée.

Ces explications peuvent en tout cas aider à comprendre l'usage qui est (encore) fait de la virgule par les juristes. La manipulation du verbe dans ce métier prend ses origines dans la déclamation et la plaidoirie, ce qui peut expliquer un attachement traditionnel à un système axé sur la respiration et l'impact sur l'auditeur.

Comment: Réponse intéressante, à laquelle il faut malheureusement rajouter que les  juristes d'aujourd'hui sont bien loin de ceux qui participèrent à l'écriture du code civil au début du XIXe, et n'ont parfois pas même conscience qu'il existe des règles _aussi_ pour la langue qu'ils emploient...